How to implement LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle) using Dart, in a real world example
The Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) states that objects of a superclass should be able to be replaced with objects of a subclass without affecting the correctness of the program. In other words, a subclass should be able to replace its superclass without breaking the code.
I'm trying to figure out how it could be a good implementation in a real world example, where we use the subclass everywhere in our code and only use the superclass on instantiation.
This is my approach:
The first shot would be something like:
class User {
  const User({
    required this.id,
    required this.avatar,
  });

  final String id;
  final String avatar;
}

class UserWithName extends User {
  const UserWithName(
      {required super.id, required super.avatar, required this.name});

  final String name;

}

void main() {
  User userWithName = new UserWithName(id: '0', avatar: 'avatar', name: 'User Name');
  
  print('hello ${(userWithName as UserWithName).name}');
}

But for me it is ugly (nedding to use the as UserWithName), and in case we want a new functionality, not parameter, as it is been ugly resolved in previous example, one could do the example below to keep in LSP, but here we are breaking the open close principle:
class User {
  const User({
    required this.id,
    required this.avatar,
  });

  final String id;
  final String avatar;

  String? getName() => null;
}

class UserWithName extends User {
  const UserWithName(
      {required super.id, required super.avatar, required this.name});

  final String name;

  String getName() => this.name;
}

void main() {
  User user = new User(id: '0', avatar: 'avatar');
  User userWithName = new UserWithName(id: '0', avatar: 'avatar', name: 'User Name');

  print('hello ${user.getName()}');
  print('hello ${userWithName.getName()}');
}

Returns:
hello null
hello User Name


Why does the second example break the open-closed principle?

In the second example we added the getName in the super class.

Oh, I think I understand what you mean now: the second example breaks OCP because to add the new named class/functionality you modified the parent class.

Yes, that's what I mean.

An instance of the subclass can substitute for an instance of the superclass in your first example. There is not issue with that. The problem is that the subclass can also do more than the superclass can, and at some point, you want to know whether you have an instance of the subclass. At that point you're moving beyond the substitution principle.
A User doesn't (necessarily) have a name. Asking for a name on something typed as User is unsafe. You should do if (user case UserWithName(:var name)) before using the name. That, or make every user have a name.

@Irn isn't that what I do in my lad post with the correct implementation?

In the real world this principle is needed in various cases, when the superclass is a grand default, yet the subclasses have the same kinds of abilities, yet, the nature of their abilities varies from the grand default.
Think of chess as a game and an engine that checks what the possible legal moves of a game might look alike. You may well have methods like

getValidMoves(...)
getValidKingMoves(...)
getValidQueenMoves(...)
getValidRookMoves(...)
getValidBishopMoves(...)
getValidKnightMoves(...)
getValidPawnMoves(...)

and all these are implemented for chess. Now, you need to implement similar classes for variants of chess, like Fischer Random Chess, Chaturanga, where you also have a table of 8x8, White and Black pieces, roughly the same starting positions (the first row and the eight's row is randomized in case of Fischer Random Chess), but the rules are different and some of the moves need to be overriden. So you create subclasses, one for each variant and override the methods.
Now, if your project is well-planned, then the engine asks for valid moves, a method that goes through all the pieces and for each piece it gets its valid moves. The results will be different, but the logic that asks for them and parses them will be the same.

Thanks for replying :-), the point I want to discuss, following your scenario: let's say that in Chaturanga the king has the power to kill all the pieces around when X condition is met, this functionality only applies to the Chaturanga subclass, how do we continue following LSP, without breaking the OCP?

@Daniel Then that would just be the implementation of getValidKingMoves in the class Chaturanga.

What I mean would be a new function that's out of superclass scope.

@Daniel you speak about a new method in a subclass but not the base class. If you want to maintain the principle, then you implement it in a dummy manner for the base class, all the subclasses will inherit it as a default behavior and you would override this for Chaturanga.

@LajosArpad yes that is the point I was making in my example, if after some time I need to implement a new method only for a subclass, to maintain LSP we need to break OCP. I was trying to find an elegant way to escape the laws of the universe apparently, thank you very much for your answers, they help me a lot to understand better.

@Daniel when you are to create newMethod() for the subclass, you create it for the base class too, so the principle is not broken. The principle is not something you necessarily need to keep, it's not written into stone, but in examples when the methods will be very similar in the base class and the subclass it makes sense to maintain it.

Finally the correct implementation, that would respect LSP and OCP, whould be:
class User {
  const User({
    required this.id,
    required this.avatar,
  });

  final String id;
  final String avatar;
}

class UserWithName extends User {
  const UserWithName(
      {required super.id, required super.avatar, required this.name});

  final String name;

  String getName() => this.name;
}

void main() {
  User user = new User(id: '0', avatar: 'avatar');
  UserWithName userWithName =
      new UserWithName(id: '0', avatar: 'avatar', name: 'User Name');

  _printUserWithName(UserWithName userWithName) {
    print('hello ${userWithName.getName()}');
  }

  if (user.runtimeType == UserWithName) {
    _printUserWithName(userWithName);
  }

  if (userWithName.runtimeType == UserWithName) {
    _printUserWithName(userWithName);
  }
}

Response:
hello User Name

